# Pin element like position: fixed but inside its parent not the viewport

Tags: html, css

I've looked around and it seems like a no-go, but I ask just in case.

Is it possible to create a sticky sidebar that follows you down the page but which stays inside of its container element?

The HTML could be something like:

```
<body>
  <header>
    Lots of random content...
  </header>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="sidebar"><!-- when you have scrolled past the header content, the sidebar should stay at the top of the page as you continue scrolling, but it should not appear on top of the header content. -->
    </div
  </div>
</body>
```

I hope this picture makes it clearer what I am wanting. So far, I have been a lousy communicator.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Simply use     position: fixed;      top: 10px; and done

Comment: That would pin the sidebar 10px from the top of the window. I am trying to pin it to the top of #parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a sticky sidebar that follows you down the
>   page but which stays inside of its container element [using HTML/CSS only]?

Like this:
http://codepen.io/jamesdarren/full/ivmcH
... but without the JavaScript.

The answer is: *At the present time, it depends on your browser.*

CSS has an experimental positioning value named [**`sticky`**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/Overview.html#sticky-pos).

By setting your sidebar to `position: sticky` it can remain fixed inside its parent container and the viewport, as opposed to just the viewport.

Here's how [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit?hl=en) describes it:

> `position: sticky` is a new way to position elements and is
>   conceptually similar to `position: fixed`. The difference is that an
>   element with `position: sticky` behaves like `position: relative`
>   within its parent, until a given offset threshold is met in the
>   viewport.

Here's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)'s take:

> Sticky positioning is a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning.  The
>   element is treated as relative positioned until it crosses a specified
>   threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed positioned.

Currently, however, [only Firefox and Safari support sticky positioning](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

Here are two demos of `position: sticky` (FF & Safari only):
http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html
http://jsfiddle.net/daker/ecpTw/light/

Here's a `position: sticky` polyfill:
https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky

*from the polyfill readme:*

> The most overlooked thing about `position: sticky` is that sticky
>   elements are constrained to the dimensions of their parent elements.

---

Lastly, should you decide to loosen your language constraints to allow scripting, here's a simple, effective and reliable solution for a sticky sidebar:

#### Tether

> Tether is a JavaScript library for efficiently making an absolutely
>   positioned element stay next to another element on the page.
>
> Tether includes the ability to constrain the element within the
>   viewport, its scroll parent, any other element on the page, or a fixed
>   bounding box.

http://github.hubspot.com/tether/

Comment: Wow, I had never heard of position:sticky. Very nice answer!

Comment: Bear in mind, this only works on a very select few of browsers, and won't provide for the majority that is IE users!

Comment: @Lee, browser limitations are already highlighted throughout my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to set the parent to have `position: relative` and the sidebar to have `position: absolute`. This way the sidebar will be relatively positioned in respect to the parent.

example css:

```
 #parent {
   position: relative;
 }
 #sidebar {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: Please take another look at the question. Your answer was correct based upon how I wrote the question. Sorry about that :/

Comment: Sorry I don't really get what you'd like to do. If you wish to achieve the effect in the link posted by @Micheal_B then you'll need to use JS (AFAIK)

Answer (score -2):

You could try this: http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/

And just use a simple javascript call for your sidebar

```
$("#sidebar").stick_in_parent();
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why the downvote? Could someone comment and maybe help me realise why this isn't the perfect solution?

Comment: Possibly because this answer goes straight into a JavaScript solution, when the question explicitly requires an HTML/CSS solution.