# What's the best way to have a table with sticky header?

Tags: html, css, html-table, sticky

What I'm currently doing is 2 tables, one for headers and one for data, in combination with `table-layout:fixed` and fixed widths for each column.

I don't like that solution since I have to keep adjusting widths and they don't look as good a the auto adjusted ones you get when the table layout isn't fixed.

I also considered a JS solution where the data table is laid out, then JS picks up each column width and applies it to the header table. The advantage of this is fluid `td` widths dictated by content. The problem is table contents can change dynamically, and the JS script needs to know that so it can recompute the widths... ew.

Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32263039/3597276

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `sticky` doesn't work with table headers unfortunately.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://www.pewforum.org/2011/01/27/table-muslim-population-by-country/

Comment: Sort of, I would like the header to be part of the table so auto-layout works equally for `<th>` and `<td>` without fixed widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better to use some plugins like [jQuery Plugin for Fix Header Table](http://www.fixedheadertable.com/)

or if you want the pure CSS and want to know how it works. you can try the below fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/

its all about showing the content if div which is inside the TH

```
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak. Clever idea. It probably won't work well with wider-than-content headers, but it's something I can work with.

Comment: How is using a *jQuery plugin* considered "better"?

Comment: @vsync Its good to use 3rd party free component which is matured because people are using over the year and fixing the issue they found and updating the library. I am okay/suggest to use the existing lib/addon available rather than writing own code which may have some issue that you encounter at production.  For quick development its good idea to re-utilise the available component rather than killing your time for same thing.