# how can I make a div scrollable on the y axis within a parent div/container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]
How can I make a div fixed /scroll within the confines of the parent element.
I have tried using various javascript functions to try and achieve this to no avail either they dont accommodate the height of the container/parent div or simply don't work-what I am trying to achieve is when the window scrolls to 60px above the red scrolling div(seen in image), it should become fixed(preferably retaining it's width) ntil it meets with the bottom of the parent/container div and then becomes position absolute within the relative parent div at "bottom:20px" **the div is relatively positioned and cannot have a scroll bar and the red div has a height smaller than that of the parent div ... it is in fixed**.Are there any javascript and/or css solutions to this problem?

here is something that I have tried
javascript:

```
    var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw),
        $bumper = $(elem),
        bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
        setPosition = function(){
            if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0
                });
            }
        };
    $window.resize(function()
    {
        bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
};

$('#one').followTo('#two');
```

html:

```
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:200px;">
    <div id="one">FIXED...</div>
    <div id="two">...BUT STOPS HERE</div>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body, html{
    height:200%;
}


#one {
    width:100%;    
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: fixed;
}


#two {
    width: 100%;    
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top:150%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: maybe my answer here will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32263039/3597276 (in particular, note the part about [**Tether**](http://github.hubspot.com/tether/).